# スワイプに表示するカスタムビューへのアクセス

Tags: android

スワイプを使用して数種類のデータを表示するアプリを作成したいと思っています。

各ページに表示するxmlは共通のものを使用し、その中に表示するカスタムビューに
各々のページのデータを表示することを考えております。
使用するカスタムビューはxmlの中で、下記のように記載しております。

```
<com.practice.test004_landscape_swipe.DrawingView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

ここで質問なのですが、このカスタムビューに何ページ目を表示しているかを
知らせる方法を知りたいと思います。
これをもとに表示するデータを選択しようと考えております。

何か方法がありましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PagerAdapterを継承したクラスを作り、オーバーライドするinstantiateItemメソッドの引数からpositionが取得出来ます。

参考：
Android Tips #30 ViewPager を使ってスワイプで View を切り替える ｜ Developers.IO http://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/android/android-tips-30-viewpager/

Comment: ありがとうございます。
positionが取得できることは理解できました。
この後、カスタムビューへpositionを渡す方法が
わからないのですが、何か方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 上記サンプルでビューのインスタンスが取得出来たかと思いますので
後はカスタムビューに番号を受け取るメソッドを作成し、それをコールすればよろしいかと思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。カスタムビューへアクセスする方法がわからなかったのですが、その後調べまして上記xmlにandroid:tag="drawview"を追加したのちinstantiateItemメソッド内でinflaterで取得したviewのfindViewWithTag("drawview")を呼び出してカスタムビューを取得、番号を設定できました。この方法でよかったのでしょうか？もっとスマートな方法がありましたら教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: なんらかの方法でviewを取得する方法があるので、inflaterを使いviewを作成する事は必要だと思います。
強いて言うのであれば、android:tag ではなくfindViewById("view1");で指摘した方がスマートと言えるかもしれません。

Comment: (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.view1);でviewを獲得できることを確認しました。